# First character replace in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have a question about SQL Server. How to replace only 1st character value when same character have multiple times?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[productdetails]
(
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [productName] [varchar](100) NULL
) 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[productdetails] ([pid], [productName]) 
VALUES (1, N'cinphol')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[productdetails] ([pid], [productName]) 
VALUES (2, N'apple')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[productdetails] ([pid], [productName]) 
VALUES (3, N'ppens')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[productdetails] ([pid], [productName]) 
VALUES (4, N'penrpos')
GO
```

Based on this data, I want output like this:

```
pid | productname
----+------------
 1  | cinZhol
 2  | azple
 3  | zpens
 4  | zenrpos
```

My query:

```
 select 
     pid, replace(productname, 'p', 'z') productname  
 from 
     productdetails
```

This query is not returning the expected results.

Could you please tell me how to achieve this task in SQL Server ?

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you actually using?? You have listed a wide range of versions in your tags - which is it you're really working with??

Comment: 2016 version using

Comment: Removed the other, useless tags

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select 
     pid,
     replace(left(productname, 1), 'p', 'z') +
       substring(productname, 2, len(productname)) productname  
 from 
     productdetails
```